# What is the meaning of 4096 in php?

Tags: php, fgets

I am a novice in php.
I can't understand a simple thing.

```
<?php 

    $users = fopen("users.txt", "r");

    while ($line = fgets($users, 4096)) {

        list($name, $occupation, $color) = explode("|", $line);

        printf("Name: %s<br/>", $name);
        printf("Occupation: %s<br/>", $occupation);
        printf("Favourite color: %s <br />", $color);
    }
    fclose($users);

 ?>
```

Here, in line `while ($line = fgets($users, 4096))` what is the meaning of `4096`?

Comment: When in doubt consult the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Answer (score 4):

It is just a maximum length of a line assumed.

According to [fgets() ocumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php),

> Reading ends when **`length` - 1** bytes have been read, or a **newline**, or an **EOF** (whichever comes first). If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.

If you don't specify `length` for PHP under 4.3.0, it will use `length = 1024`.
If you don't specify `length` in newer versions, it will read until it reaches the end of the line.

I may guess several reasons of specifying `length`:

- compatibility with older versions. Older versions would use `length = 1024`. If you have longer lines in your file, it is better to specify the maximum possible length to it;
- if you want to read not more than `n` characters from a line;
- also, probably, specifying a limited `length` has a positive impact on performance somehow (*please, correct me if I am wrong*).

So, in new versions, if you want to read the whole line - don't use `length` or set it to the maximum possible length of a line in your input.